# Оптимизация кода в PHP (шаблонизатор)

Tags: php, оптимизация, шаблоны

Привет всем! PHP изучаю давно, вот перешел на шаблоны. Появился такой вопрос по оптимизации кода. У меня есть шаблон и сам шаблонизатор, а так же главная страница.

Вот шаблонизатор:

```
<?php
class parse_class
{
var $vars = array();
var $template;

function get_tpl($tpl_name)
  {
  if(empty($tpl_name) || !file_exists($tpl_name))
    {
    return false;
    }
  else
    {
    $this->template  = file_get_contents($tpl_name);
    }
  }
function set_tpl($key,$var)
  {
  $this->vars[$key] = $var;
  }
function tpl_parse()
  {
  foreach($this->vars as $find => $replace)
         {
         $this->template = str_replace($find, $replace, $this->template);
         }
  }
}
$parse = new parse_class;
?>
```

вот шаблон

```
<html>
  <head>
        <title>{title}</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
        {content}
  </body>
```

Собственно вопрос: можно ли как то оптимизировать следующий код, чтобы не писать по многу раз одни и те же функции:

```
    $parse->set_tpl('{title}','Заголовок сайта'); 
    $parse->set_tpl('{content}','Контент сайта');
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: во-первых уберите из `set_tpl` скобки и перенесите их в `tpl_parse` чтоб было `str_replace('{'.$find.'}', ...` вы же точно знаете, что парсятся такие значения, так зачем проблемы создавать в передаче имен? во-вторых можно передавать в `set_tpl` ассоциативный массив - ключ значение: `set_tpl(['title'=>'заголовок', 'content' => 'контент'])`, а в функции уже пробежаться по нему и занести всё в `$this->vars`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не шаблонизатор. А типичное заблуждение всех начинающих шаблонописателей.

В реальной жизни это не будет работать.

Потому что реальный контент не состоит из строчки "контент сайта". На самом деле он состоит из сотен сток чистого как слеза HTML.

И если мы ваяем весь этот HTML в коде скрипта, то разумеется, ни о каком использовании шаблонов речь в принципе не идет.

Рекомендую любые свои идеи проверять на хотя бы минимально приближенных к реальной жизни примерах.

И после такой проверки сделать следующий шаг всех шаблонописателей - написать обертку над include, вида

```
public function render($template, $data)
{
    extract ($data);
    include $template;
}
```

Этого в реальной жизни тоже будет недостаточно, но этот шаблонизатор хотя бы в минимальной степени может называться таковым, позволяя отделять логику приложения от логики отображения.

Comment: можете рассказать  подробней про extract, как я понимаю полученные переменные нужно использовать для записи в них как раз таки сотен строк HTML кода?

Comment: Нет в полученные переменные надо записывать переданные из в шаблонизатор переменные. А вот файл $template должен представлять из себя РНР файл, в котором эти переменные выводятся, обычным порядком, `<?=$title?>`

Comment: Для практики рекомендую написать шаблон для вывода сообщений гостевой книги. С тем, чтобы HTML присутствовал только в шаблоне.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо **Алексею** за комментарий.
Посидел, разобрался, вот что в итоге получилось:

**Шаблонизатор:**

```
<?php
class pattern // Создаем класс шаблонизатора.
{ 
  public $template; // Переменная, в которую запишем оригинальный шаблон, а затем модифицированый.

  function get_tpl($tpl_name) // Получаем файл шаблона.
  {
      if(!empty($tpl_name) || file_exists($tpl_name)) $this->template  = file_get_contents($tpl_name); // Проверяем
      // Проверим, есть ли файл шаблона и не пустой ли он.
      else return false; // В противном случае вернем false.
  }
  function tpl_construct($dataarr) // "Построение" шаблона.
  {
      foreach($dataarr as $key => $value) $this->template = str_replace($key, $value, $this->template);
      // Через foreach заменяем все значения в шаблоне на значения, полученные из массива.
  }
}
?>
```

**И сама страничка:**

```
<?php
require('./templates/pattern.class.php'); // Подгружаем шаблонизатор.
$pattern = new pattern; // Создаем объект шаблонизатора.
$pattern->get_tpl('./templates/default/template.tpl'); // Указываем путь к файлу шаблона.
// Массив с данными.
$data = array (
    "{title}" => "заголовок",
    "{content}" => "контент",
);
$pattern->tpl_construct($data); // Меняем значения в шаблоне на значения в массиве.
print $pattern->template; // Отображаем страницу.
?>
```